# How to Get Bourbon, Neat, Bitters & Refills to Work Together

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

It seems to me that there are some conflicts between Bourbon, Bitters, Neat and Refills. I have gotten errors about undefined variables and mixins. From searching around, my understanding is that Bitters requires version 5.0 beta of Bourbon whereas Refills does not work with version 5.0.

As such, I am wondering how to get started with all four elements. That is to say, which versions should I download so that I can have a working system until such time as refills is updated?

Thanks and be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you’re correct: Refills is currently the one piece that isn’t compatible with Bourbon 5.

If you want to use Refills here’s what versions you need:

- Bourbon <= 4.2.7
- Neat <= 1.8.0
- Bitters <= 1.2.0

Just want to stress that these are old version; it’s Refills that has fallen out of date and is the trouble. We are working on a major revamp of Refills, but it’s not going to be ready soon.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  When you say that these are old versions -- is there anything that I need to worry about in using them?